# what is the formal way to write this

Tags: grammar

During a self-introduction in class, Jan said,
"Hi my name's Jan Wayne. My friends call me Jan."

I want to write these sentences down formally, but I don't know how to.

Comment: Since they are in quotes, and presumably are a correct representation of what Jan said, you have already done so. That is the correct way to write those sentences. As for formality, that depends entirely on the situation; there is not one single way to be formal. There are, instead, dozens of ways to be **more** formal, which can be used simultaneously. Formality is a social matter, not a separate verb form like the past tense.

Comment: You might be interested in the [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 1):

I would only add that in such written quotations, we often put a comma after Hello, to indicate a brief pause.